# Error uploading large files (>2gb) through nginx reverse proxy to container

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, containers, upload

I am running an application in a docker container (https://github.com/filebrowser/filebrowser/) that I am trying to upload very large (>2) GB files to. The container exposes the app on a nonstandard port on localhost which I connect to through a reverse proxy (so I can run multiple apps on one machine). The problem is when I upload a file over 2097152 bytes it errors out. I can see that the files is fully uploaded to nginx and that it partially makes it to the contianerized app but then hangs for a long time at 2097152 bytes before erroring out causing the containerized app to give a unexpected EOF error. I suspect it's something wrong with nginx becuase when I upload a file to the containerized app directly it works fine. I've tried adding a variety of directives to the nginx config and am stumped. My nginx config for the site is:

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    client_max_body_size    30g;
    proxy_buffer_size       1024k;
    proxy_buffers 4 1024k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 1024k;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 10000m;
    proxy_connect_timeout   10000;
    proxy_send_timeout      10000;
    proxy_read_timeout      10000;
    send_timeout            10000;
    client_header_timeout   10000;
    client_body_timeout     10000;
    
    location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8088/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

    proxy_set_header Upgrade           $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection        "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host              $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;

    proxy_connect_timeout              10000s;
    proxy_send_timeout                 10000s;
    proxy_read_timeout                 10000s;
    }}
```

The error I get in nginx is:

```
2022/04/14 20:26:56 [error] 3286524#3286524: *13184 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: example.com, request: "POST /api/resources/Fedora-KDE-Live-x86_64-35-1.2.iso?override=false HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://[::1]:8088/api/resources/Fedora-KDE-Live-x86_64-35-1.2.iso?override=false", host: "example.com", referrer: "https://example.com/files/"
```

Edit: After doing lots of digging, it seems that the solution was to remove the `proxy_buffer_size`, `proxy_buffers`, and `proxy_busy_buffer_size` and add `proxy_request_buffering off;` I don't know why this works but it does. The modified lines in the config were:

```
    # proxy_buffer_size       1024k;
    # proxy_buffers 4 1024k;
    # proxy_busy_buffers_size 1024k;
    proxy_request_buffering off;
```

Comment: Thanks for asking and sharing part of your solution. When you write "remove the proxy_buffer_size", do you mean that you are using the defaults? or set it to 0? Please share the actual config lines you are using, thanks in advance!
I have a similar problem, nginx is out-of-memory (oom) killed due to spiking in memory use at the end of big uploads.

Comment: @klausthorn When I say I "removed proxy_buffer_size" I meant I commented out those lines in the config and used the default values. I'm not sure what those values are but I'm running nginx/1.18.0 on Raspberry Pi OS 64 bit. Hopefully this helps with your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer:

- [`proxy_request_buffering off;`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_request_buffering) fixes your issue because that is the only option that is relevant to **uploads** (requests).

---

All the other options apply only to **downloads** to the client (responses). Quoting from the docs:

- [`proxy_buffer_size`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_buffer_size)

  > ... size of the buffer used for reading the first part of the **response** received from the proxied server ...
- [`proxy_buffers`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_buffers)

  > ... buffers used for reading a **response** from the proxied server ...
- [`proxy_busy_buffers_size`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_busy_buffers_size)

  > ... When buffering of **responses** from the proxied server ...

Answer (score 0):

I also hit the 2GB limit. `proxy_request_buffering off;` did not work for me. Adding the two options below to the `/` location is the only thing that did work for me:

```
proxy_buffering      off;
client_max_body_size 0;
```